# SSL Issue - Laravel 9 using Flysystem 3.x gets Unable to check existence for when calling the Storage exists() method for AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, laravel-9

I have a laravel project I just upgraded from 8.x to the latest 9.x.
As part of that upgrade it required many other components like the file system (I guess called flysystem) to also be upgraded from 1.x to 3.x.
I have a line of code that is now causing my system to crash:

```
if (Storage::disk($disk)->exists($avatarFilename)) {
```

This has always worked before but now it is returning:

```
ERROR: Unable to check existence for: avatars/31-feea15debc.png
[stacktrace]
#0 D:\\vhosts\\vendor\\league\\flysystem-aws-s3-v3\\AwsS3V3Adapter.php(157): League\\Flysystem\\UnableToCheckExistence::forLocation('avatars/31-feea...', Object(Aws\\S3\\Exception\\S3Exception))
#1 D:\\vhosts\\vendor\\league\\flysystem\\src\\Filesystem.php(48): League\\Flysystem\\AwsS3V3\\AwsS3V3Adapter->directoryExists('avatars/31-feea...')
#2 D:\\vhosts\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Filesystem\\FilesystemAdapter.php(174): League\\Flysystem\\Filesystem->has('avatars/31-feea...')
#3 D:\\vhosts\\app\\Models\\User.php(1120): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\FilesystemAdapter->exists('avatars/31-feea...')
#4 D:\\vhosts\\scoutek.com\\storage\\framework\\views\\eb5469bb9d755dff931d80dd79d9a76a9a7a2a21.php(10): App\\Models\\User->getAvatar()
```

After digging deep through several thousand lines reported into my Laravel log file I found the following which looks like it is the cause of the exception:

```
(Aws\\S3\\Exception\\S3Exception(code: 0): Error executing 
\"ListObjects\" on 
\"https://scoutek-development.s3.amazonaws.com/?prefix=avatars%2F31-feea15debc.png%2F&max-keys=1&delimiter=%2F&encoding-type=url\"; 
AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: 
unable to get local issuer certificate 
(see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for
```

I have used OpenSSL and created my key and certificate files and referenced them in apache conf files and when I run phpinfo() I can see all of my localhost certificate data that I input while creating the certificate so it appears php is aware of the certificate.
I am running WAMP 3.2.3, PHP 8.1.5, Apache 2.4.46

Comment: have you found the solutions? please let me know. i had the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out I needed to do the following:

- Download the latest cacert.pem file from https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html
- Copy the cacert.pem file to my php8.1.5/extras/ssl folder
- update both php.ini and phpForApache.ini to add the following:

  curl.cainfo = "D:\wamp3.2.3\bin\php\php8.1.5\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"

Answer (score 1):

In case other people have the same issue, but the above solution did not solve it for you:

I got the same error after upgrading to Laravel 9. Turns out we were passing `$variable = false` to the `Resource::cloud()->exists($variable)` check, which in the latest version is no longer supported. So a good thing is to double check that you're passing a supported value into this function.

Comment: I had the same issue with checking s3 file exists. Can you tell me how to fix it.When I use "if (Storage::exists($location . $fName))" , it always returns exceptions. unable to use existence

Comment: Similar issue. Checking the value passed to exists/has() isn't null worked for me.

Comment: Exactly. So if you're doing the check in an if statement, you can solve it by adding an empty check in front of it: `if (!empty($variable) && Resource::cloud()->exists($variable)) { ...`

Answer (score 1):

I fixed a similar issue with this config.

```php
'use_path_style_endpoint' => true,
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help anyone else, but I just ran into this problem and was using a raw endpoint url without the `https://` protocol prefix. Adding the prefix fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just because nobody has mentioned, the response from AWS for me was:

Error executing "HeadObject" on "......"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `HEAD ......` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response (client): 403 Forbidden (Request-ID: JMN.......A)

So I was trying to check the existence of a file in a folder that did not exist. It is still confusing to me why it is throwing an exception instead of returning a boolean response.

Please make sure to check whether the file and the folder exist.

Answer (score -1):

In my dockerfile I added this line:

```
RUN echo culr.cainfo="/etc/cacert.pem" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-curl-ca-cert.ini
```